# Generate tikz coordinate for each line from minted file included

Tags: tikz-pgf, minted

I want to include a file `../basename.end` via minted and automatically generate a tikz-coordinate `basename-$LINENUMBER` for the beginning of each line of the included file...

I fumbled around with something found in [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271115/increase-counter-for-each-line-in-custom-align-environment), but didn't get far... any hints?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% enable global node labeling
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

% set default basename for coordinates labels
\tikzset{/minted/basename/.initial=minted}

% optional: set up line numbering style redefining \theFancyVerbLine BEFORE
% the next step (or empty it if you don't want numbering, since the use of
% linenos is mandatory)

% prepend (or append using \appto) the tikz coordinate to the line numbering
\preto\theFancyVerbLine%
  {\tikz\coordinate(\pgfkeysvalueof{/minted/basename}-\arabic{FancyVerbLine});}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[linenos]{c}
  int main() {
    printf("hello, world");
    return 0;
  }
\end{minted}

% use the labeled coordinates
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \path[->, thick] (minted-1) edge [bend right=90] (minted-4);
  \fill[red] (minted-3) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

% if you want to use a custom basename for coordinates labels:
%\tikzset{/minted/basename=mycode}

% if you want to input an external file:
%\inputminted[linenos]{c}{mycode.c}

\end{document}
```

And here is the result:

[image: shazaam]

There is space for improvements:

- better coordinate alignment (a matter of simple TiKz styling, but what's *better* depends on what you need to do and you have not been specific);
- automatic coordinate basename (a tighter integration with `minted` is needed so that's feasible but the benefit is probably not worth the effort).

However, this code gets the basic job done and should get you going.

Comment: While this works, it is incredible slow when using lots of tikzpictures (and pgfplots) probably due to the global node labeling?
Is there another way of adding the tikz nodes in the code lines manually? I only need nodes at a few lines.

Comment: If the global node labeling actually is the problem, you can limit that to a scope (`\begingroup` ... `\endgroup`) enclosing the `remember picture` setting, the `minted environment` and the overlayed `tikzpicture` within which you refer to the line nodes. (As always, an MWE pinpointing the critical situation would be useful.)

Comment: That does actually speed things up very much, thanks!
How can I control the horizontal whitespace between the numberings and the actual code? There is some in the result you posted and in my case there's almost half the page white in between!

Comment: Nevermind. The indentation of the code itself in the .tex file caused the skip. Aligning it at the very left solved it.

Comment: @Christoph90 Use the option `gobble=n` for the minted environment to unindent each line. There's also `autogobble` which detects common the length of common white spaces at the start of each line.